# How to filter DataView based on multiple inputs

Tags: c#, filter, dataview

I know how to filter data based on the user's input from a single textbox:

FilterDataView.RowFilter = txtFilter.Text;

But how would you go about filtering data based on multiple user input from multiple fields.
Basically filter would act as a "search" functionality.

Comment: Do you mean the user for example could enter a keyword, select an option from a dropdownlist, and select a date range?

Comment: No. there are 4 textboxes and if user fill them all out and presses filter he will find a particular record, but if he inputs only 1 of the textboxes he will get more results. Example if he inputs fname, lname, city, profession he will find a single person, but if user enters only city then user gets only records whose persons live in that city.

Comment: Is the dataview being bound to a query that you can apply successive Where clauses to? This would be easy in Linq.  If that works for you, let me know and I can provide an example.

Comment: LINQ would suffice, but I never used LINQ. The DataView's DataSource is binded to a single table with a couple of records.

Comment: I'm not sure how to do this with a datasource. LIke nycdan said, if you use LINQ it would be cake.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use something like light t-sql when defining RowFilter.

One idea is:

```
FilterDataView.RowFilter = "name like '%habjan%' and city like '%new york%'"
```

Here you can find a good article about RowFilter syntax: [DataView RowFilter Syntax](http://erison.blogspot.com/2010/03/dataview-rowfilter-syntax-c.html)

For what you need you will have to build row filter based on entered fields.

```
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    if (tb1.Text.Length > 0)
    {
       sb.Append("name like '%" + tb1.Text + "%'");
    }

    if (tb2.Text.Length > 0)
    {
       if(sb.Length > 0)
       {
           sb.Append(" and ");
       }

       sb.Append("city like '%" + tb2.Text + "%'");
    }
    //.... and so on...

    FilterDataView.RowFilter = sb.ToString();
```

Comment: Interesting, but there are few syntax errors. The second % has wrong quotes to the left. Also when I this method the program gives me an error pointing at FilterDataView.RowFilter = sb.ToString(); saying that tb1.text column couldn't be found. But isn't it a textbox?

Comment: @HelloWorld: Sorry, i did not use code editor to write this code, i wrote it directly here.

Comment: @HelloWorld: i fixed quotes problem.

Comment: It works! But one of my textboxes accepts only numbers(it actually validates input through int.TryParse()) and when I try to execute the filter: Cannot perform 'Like' operation on System.Int32 and System.String

Comment: for numeric value you can write something like this: "city like '%xxx%' and age=32"

Comment: Yes but the number comes from a textbox, so hardcoding a value into the sql won't work. This number corresponds to a column names BookCode in my table.

Comment: sb.Append("age=" + tb3.Text);

Answer (score 1):

Search the MSDN(LINQ to DataSet)
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb669073.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Okay, Linq to SQL is going to be your friend.

You need to learn the syntax, and there are a few different forms, but you can recreate your query in this way:

```
var x = from T in db.Table
        where [usual where stuff goes here];
```

Then, you can test each textbox and do the following:

```
if (TextBox1.Text != null) x.Where(w => w.field1 == val1);
```

The nice thing is you can layer those Where clauses one at a time.  Then just bind your object to the var.

```
[objectname].Datasource = x; 
[objectname].Databind();
```

That should solve your problem.

Comment: Okay Ill try to make it work. Will it refresh the DataGridView?

Comment: not sure if you still want to do it this way, but it's worth trying for the flexibility.  Yes, when you do the .Databind() it will refresh the datagridview.