# Show Multiple Data to Datagridview using C#

Tags: c#, datagridview

I want to show multiple data based on value I input to textboxes. I have data such as :

```
WSID   CasA   CasB 
1234   200    100   
5678   300    200
0987   400    300
6543   500    400
```

If I input in CasA textbox = 200 and CasB textbox = 200, WSID 1234 and 5678 will be shown. I got some problem, if I input value like above, it just show WSID of CasB. Can anyone help me ?

```
string lokasinectar = LokasiNectar.Text;
string koneksinectar = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + lokasinectar + ";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 xml;HDR=YES;IMEX=1';";

int thresholdcasa;
Int32.TryParse(CasA.Text, out thresholdcasa);

int thresholdcasb;
Int32.TryParse(CasB.Text, out thresholdcasb);

OleDbConnection kon = new OleDbConnection(koneksinectar);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("select [WSID], [CasA], [CasB] from [Sheet1$]", kon);
DataSet coba = new DataSet();
adapter.Fill(coba);

var table = coba.Tables[0];
var view = new DataView(table);

if (CasAChk.Checked)
{
    if (CasA.Text.Length > 0)
    {

        view.RowFilter = string.Format("[CasA] = '{0}'", thresholdcasa);
    }
}
else if (CasBChk.Checked)
{
    if (CasB.Text.Length > 0)
    {
        view.RowFilter = string.Format("[CasB] ='{0}'", thresholdcasb);
    }  
}

ViewNectarGV.DataSource = view;
```

Comment: When is your code running? Is it during an event e.g. after checking a check box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are building your `RowFilter` in an `if... else if` statement, hence only one code block or the other can be executed.  You need to build a dynamic filter which appends all columns you wish to filter by, joined by an `OR`.  Largely borrowed from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5489589/3773066), try the following:

```
int temp = 0;
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

if (CasAChk.Checked && Int32.TryParse(CasA.Text, out temp))
{
    sb.Append(string.Format("[CasA] = '{0}'", temp));
}

if (CasBChk.Checked && Int32.TryParse(CasB.Text, out temp))
{
    if (sb.Length > 0)
    {
        sb.Append(" OR ");
    }

    sb.Append(string.Format("[CasB] = '{0}'", temp));
}

view.RowFilter = sb.ToString();

ViewNectarGV.DataSource = view;
```

Comment: Ahh thanks so much ! It works ! :) I want to ask you once again. How can I set their each column color ? For example for CasA, I want to color its output column as red, and yellow for output of CasB @OhBeWise

Comment: After setting the `DataSource`, you can set `yourDataGridView.Columns[desiredColumnIndex].DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor` or `.BackColor` to your preferred color.

Comment: Mmm. I mean, for example when the desired result is shown, its column will be blue and another will be white. So, when 200 of CasA is shown, its color of column will be change and the color of 300, 400, amd 500 will not change. Can you help me ?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want to color just the cells that were matched in the filter?

Comment: Yes I do. Can you help me ?

Comment: Without doing the work for you, I can tell you that to do this you should handle the `DataGridView.CellFormatting` event.  The second parameter, `DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e`, contains the `RowIndex` and `ColumnIndex` of the cell being formatted.  You can use this information to compare the cell's value against the same outermost if-conditions as posted above for the filters. Then, you can change the cell's `.Style.ForeColor` to your color for a match, else black.