# how to apply row filter in multiple columns to search data from xml

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, rowfilter

I am able to get searching of my grid individually but how to apply row filter with multiple parameters in C#

Here is code which I am trying to search in C# on Click event

```
 string FirstName = txtFirstName.Text.Trim();
    string Lastname = txtLastName.Text.Trim();
    string EmployeeID = txtEmployeeID.Text.Trim();
    string Department = txtDepartment.Text.Trim();
    string Application = ddlApplication0.SelectedItem.Text.Trim();
    int sApplication = ddlApplication0.SelectedIndex;
    string Action = ddlAction0.SelectedItem.Text.Trim();
    int iAction = ddlAction0.SelectedIndex;
```

And this is working individually

```
if (table.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(FirstName))
    {
        table.DefaultView.RowFilter = "FirstName = '" + FirstName + "'";
        table = table.DefaultView.ToTable();
        dsquery = table.DefaultView.ToTable();
    }
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Lastname))
    {
        table.DefaultView.RowFilter = "Lastname = '" + Lastname + "'";
        table = table.DefaultView.ToTable();
        dsquery = table.DefaultView.ToTable();
    }
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(EmployeeID))
    {
        table.DefaultView.RowFilter = "EmployeeID = '" + EmployeeID + "'";
        table = table.DefaultView.ToTable();
        dsquery = table.DefaultView.ToTable();
    }
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Department))
    {
        table.DefaultView.RowFilter = "Department = '" + Department + "'";
        table = table.DefaultView.ToTable();
        dsquery = table.DefaultView.ToTable();
    }
    if ((sApplication.ToString() != "0"))
    {
        table.DefaultView.RowFilter = "Application = '" + Application + "'";
        table = table.DefaultView.ToTable();
        dsquery = table.DefaultView.ToTable();
    }
    if ((iAction.ToString() != "0"))
    {
        table.DefaultView.RowFilter = "Action = '" + Action + "'";
        table = table.DefaultView.ToTable();
        dsquery = table.DefaultView.ToTable();
    }
    if (rdInprogress.Checked)
    {

        table.DefaultView.RowFilter = "Status = '" + "New Request" + "'";
        table = table.DefaultView.ToTable();
        dsquery = table.DefaultView.ToTable();
    }
    if (rdnRequestCompleted.Checked)
    {
        table.DefaultView.RowFilter = "Status = '" + "Request Completed" + "'";
        table = table.DefaultView.ToTable();
        dsquery = table.DefaultView.ToTable();
    }

}
```

Now how to apply filter multiple times in C#. So that if user fill any of them search happens in grid. How to combine it ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to filter DataView based on multiple inputs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5489398/how-to-filter-dataview-based-on-multiple-inputs)

Comment: you have to design a *select* query for in **where** clause.